# VS 2013 error C1853 trying to build DLL (but not using precompiled headers set)

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

Hello I'm trying to build the simplest possible DLL in C using VS2013 community edition. I set "Not using Precompiled Headers" in the options (although somehow the project creation wizard seems to indicate that Using Precompiled Headers is 
imposed because it's a greyed check option. Anyway I decide to turn it off uing the menus associated with the project properties anyway.) But I still get this error saying

> Error 1   error C1853: 'Release\ExportDLLVars.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)   D:\devt\CplusPlus\Tests\ExportDLLVars\ExportDLLVars\VarsSource.c    1   1   ExportDLLVars

I have created a default DLL project using the wizard and added the following two source files

```
#define NAME_SIZE 80
struct _Person
{
char name[NAME_SIZE];
int tel_nb;
int age;
};

#ifdef EXPORTDLLVARS_EXPORTS
#define DLL_VAR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_VAR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_VAR int get_age();
DLL_VAR void set_age(int a);
DLL_VAR extern struct _Person ThePerson;
```

as the header file VarsSource.h and the C file is this:

```
#include "VarsSource.h"
DLL_VAR struct _Person ThePerson;
DLL_VAR int get_age(){ return ThePerson.age; }
DLL_VAR void set_age(int a){ ThePerson.age = a; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The wizard creates a C++ project. Your C file cannot share precompiled headers with the C++ files generated by the wizard, which is what this part of the error means: `or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C`.

Try the following:

- Do a full Clean for all configurations.
- Remove the `stdafx.cpp` file from the project.
- Recheck the project settings and make sure that Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Precompiled Headers has them turned off *both* at the project level, *and* for each C/C++ file individually.